# Не работает функция при вызове 2 раза с разными параметрами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть [функция](https://codepen.io/porsake/pen/xxEOOPG), которая за заданное количество секунд увеличивает значение от 1 до заданного числа

```
const time = 5000;
const step = 1;

function outNum(num, elem) {
    let e = document.querySelector(elem);
    n = 0;
    let t = Math.round(time / (num / step));
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        n = n + step;
        if (n == num) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        e.innerHTML = n;
    }, t);
}
```

Если мы вызываем функцию один раз с заданными параметрами, то функция отрабатывает верно. Например: `outNum(125, ".js-bonus1");`

Но если мы вызываем одновременно 2 функции с разными параметрами, то функция уже работает неправильно:

```
outNum(125, ".js-bonus1");
outNum(250, ".js-bonus2");
```

В чем проблема? Как запустить функцию два раза одновременно?

Comment: добавь асинхронность